# Java array outputting "null"

Tags: java

The program is supposed to store input of 2 team names and 2 scores, after doing so it should output them.

The array is just printing "null [null] | null [null]"

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class C3484209 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] home_team_name = new String[100];
        String[] away_team_name = new String[100];
        String[] home_team_score = new String[100];
        String[] away_team_score = new String[100];

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line = "";

        while (!(line.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")))
        {

                System.out.println("Enter the teams that played and the score :");
                System.out.println("(Please note that the standard format is Home team : Away Team : Home Score : Away Score)");
                line = keyboard.nextLine();

                String[] elements = line.split(": ");


                    for ( int i = 0; i < elements.length; )
                    {
                        if ((int)i == 0)
                        {
                            home_team_name[i] = elements[0];
                            i++;
                        }
                        else if ((int)i == 1)
                        {
                            away_team_name[i] = elements[1];
                            i++;
                        }
                        else if ((int)i == 2)
                        {
                            home_team_score[i] = elements[2];
                            i++;
                        }
                        else if((int)i == 3)
                        {
                            away_team_score[i] = elements[3];
                            i++;
                        }
                        //System.out.print("Element " + (i+1) + " was : " + elements[i] + " | ");
                        System.out.println(home_team_name[i] + " [" + home_team_score[i] + "]" + " | " + away_team_name[i] +" [" + away_team_score[i] + "]");

                    }

        }
        //Output Command

        keyboard.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like a simple homework assignment in an intro to programming class.  Your best bet is a spin in a debugger to see where your assumptions fail to match reality.  Believe the JVM - those values are null because you aren't setting them properly.  It might be too early in your course, but I'd recommend creating a Java object to encapsulate those values, with a proper toString method to print them.  You can have a List of objects that will be far easier to deal with.

Comment: shouldn't that `System.out.println` statement at the end of your `for loop` be out of the scope of that for loop ? First you need to set all the values before printing them out. I tried compiling your code after putting `System.out.println` statement out of that `for loop` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing just a simple mistake. You are saving value to you String[] arrays with the index i which should be reverse like

```
if ((int) i == 0) {
                home_team_name[k] = elements[i];

            }
```

array starts from index 0 and you are saving you value at different index

you should try this!

```
package stackoverflow;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class C3484209 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] home_team_name = new String[100];
    String[] away_team_name = new String[100];
    String[] home_team_score = new String[100];
    String[] away_team_score = new String[100];

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String line = "";

    int k = 0;
    while (!(line.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))) {

        System.out.println("Enter the teams that played and the score :");
        System.out.println(
                "(Please note that the standard format is Home team : Away Team : Home Score : Away Score)");
        line = keyboard.nextLine();

        String[] elements = line.split(": ");

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if ((int) i == 0) {
                home_team_name[k] = elements[i];

            } else if ((int) i == 1) {
                away_team_name[k] = elements[i];

            } else if ((int) i == 2) {
                home_team_score[k] = elements[i];

            } else if ((int) i == 3) {
                away_team_score[k] = elements[i];

            }
        }
        System.out.println(home_team_name[k] + " [" + home_team_score[k] + "]" + " | " + away_team_name[k] + " ["
                + away_team_score[k] + "]");
        k++;

    }
    keyboard.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
package cn.sehzh;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] home_team_name = new String[100];
        String[] away_team_name = new String[100];
        String[] home_team_score = new String[100];
        String[] away_team_score = new String[100];

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line = "";

        int j = 0;
        while (!(line.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))) {

            System.out.println("Enter the teams that played and the score :");
            System.out.println(
                    "(Please note that the standard format is Home team : Away Team : Home Score : Away Score)");
            line = keyboard.nextLine();

            String[] elements = line.split(": ");

            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length;) {
                if ((int) i == 0) {
                    home_team_name[j] = elements[0];
                    i++;
                } else if ((int) i == 1) {
                    away_team_name[j] = elements[1];
                    i++;
                } else if ((int) i == 2) {
                    home_team_score[j] = elements[2];
                    i++;
                } else if ((int) i == 3) {
                    away_team_score[j] = elements[3];
                    i++;
                }
            }
            // System.out.print("Element " + (i+1) + " was : " + elements[i]
            // + " | ");
            System.out.println(home_team_name[j] + " [" + home_team_score[j] + "]" + " | " + away_team_name[j] + " ["
                    + away_team_score[j] + "]");
            j++;

        }
        // Output Command

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

You should learn how to debug!